# What is process in Markov Decision Process?

Tags: markov-process

From all the explanations I have had, I only get what the *Markov* part of MDP is, not the *process* part of it. Is it same as the *process* as used in stochastic processes, gaussian processes or poisson processes?

I can't get a Wikipedia link to *process* and the definitions of MDP or any of the aforementioned processes do not go as *"Stochastic process is a process which..."*. Maybe examples of generic processes and defining these as special cases would help me understand better.

Comment: 1. Yes, it is the same.  2. A Markov Chain has a discrete state space and/or a discrete time index, so it's a subset of Markov processes.  3. A Markov decision process is a Markov process in which, at certain epochs and certain states, an external process, for example, you, makes a decision that affects the evolution of the MDP.  If you have a fixed decision rule, the MDP *given the decision rule* is a Markov process.  If you change the decision rule, it's a different Markov process but the same MDP.

Comment: I think the Wikipedia link might help:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain

Comment: In general, a stochastic "process" is a collection of random variables $\{X_t : t\in \mathbb T\}$ where $\mathbb T$ is an indexing set. Often $\mathbb T=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ (which we consider a "discrete-time" process) or $\mathbb T=[0,\infty)$ (which we consider a "continuous-time" process).

Comment: @Math1000 So, MDP = {??? : t ∈ T}, what goes in there?